# Vscode extension code error "transport target for "..\..\lib\logger\transformStream"

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, typescript

I'm trying to create a new VsCode extension that connects to the default salesforce org using the npm package @salesforce/core with typescript.

the code is the following:

```
// The module 'vscode' contains the VS Code extensibility API
// Import the module and reference it with the alias vscode in your code below
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import { Messages, AuthInfo, Connection } from '@salesforce/core';

// This method is called when your extension is activated
// Your extension is activated the very first time the command is executed
export async function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "apex-class-helper" is now active!');

    // My custom code starts here
    const username = 'username123456@curious-narwhal-3flfcn.com';
    const authInfo = await AuthInfo.create({ username });

    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('apex-class-helper.ApexHelper', () => {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World from Apex Class Helper!');
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

// This method is called when your extension is deactivated
export function deactivate() {}
```

First I compile this and open in the developement instance of Vscode using F5.
Whenever I try to launch the extension using ctrl+shift+p --> name of the extension I get this error.

[image: Error message]

I searched on Google but I only found 1 github issue in the forcedotcom.cli repo with no solution.

Comment: I'm not sure you can call sf cli as a direct dependency of your vscode extension, the pattern is more to call it via command with exec() or similar instructions, and define sf cli installation as pre-requisite to use your extension. That's how sf vs code extensions and sfdx-hardis extension are working :)

Comment: thanks @nicolas-vuillamy.
can you check the answer bellow ?

Comment: If you find a way to make it work, that's great :)
But i still think that using exec is a better way, because people anyway people need to have sf cli installed, and having a different sf cli on their computer and within your extension could be not that good, and u'll also need to publish new versions of your extension everytime SF cli releases a new version ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the insight @nicolas-vuillamy.

I got it to work by creating a new project without using webpack to bundle the source.
The code looks like that:

```
import { AuthInfo, Connection, ConfigAggregator } from '@salesforce/core';

export async function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const aggregator = await ConfigAggregator.create();
    const username = aggregator.getPropertyValue('target-org') as string;

    const authInfo = await AuthInfo.create({ username });
    const connection = await Connection.create({ authInfo });
    
    //fetch apex classes
    const result = await connection.tooling.query<{ Name: string; Id: string; SymbolTable: SymbolTable }>(
    'SELECT id, Name, SymbolTable FROM ApexClass');

    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('apex-class-  helper.ApexHelper', () => {
        
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}
```

Here I'm using the tooling API to get some classes info.

Do you think that's an OK way do it or using exec() is the better way ?
Thanks